# Establish the inequality $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n-i+1} < \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality

Given a finite increasing sequence of real numbers $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ consisting of at least two elements, how can we show that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n-i+1} < \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^2
$$
without expanding. I attempted applying Holder's inequality but failed. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) the sum in LHS is by [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) the lowest possible of form $x_ix_{\pi(i)}$ where $\pi$ is a permutation.

2) unless the $x_i$ are *strictly* increasing somewhere, equality is possible.

---

P.S. For some more detail, note that $n\sum x_ix_{n−i+1}<\left(\sum x_i\right)^2$ follows from $n$ rearrangements summed together.  Each such rearrangement has an RHS of form $\sum x_i x_{i+j}$ where $j=0,1,...n−1$, and the sum in LHS is lower than each of them.

Comment: Thank you @Macavity. But I have one more question. I still don't get it how to justify the removal of the absolute values. Do I need to resort on case to case basis?

Comment: There are no absolute values in what I hinted. I am not attempting to salvage your efforts, just note that $n \sum x_i x_{n-i+1} < (\sum x_i)^2$ follows from $n$ rearrangements summed together - the RHS contains terms $n$ sums of (cyclic) form $\sum_i x_i x_{i+j}$ where $j=0, 1, ... n-1$, and the sum in LHS is lower than each of them.

Comment: Great! Now I get it. Thanks once again.

Comment: We don't need strict increase, just that $x_1\lt x_n$.

Comment: @robjohn  Yes. Equality in rearrangement requires all the variables to be identical.

Comment: It would be nice to give a link to [The Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Thanks @robjohn, added that in the main text.

Comment: @Macavity: it would be nice if  the content of your first comment, which is pretty important to the answer, were included in your answer.

Comment: @robjohn Added.  Please feel free to edit if you think more is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should be wrong.
For example for $x_i = 1$ this is an equality isn't it?
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} 1^2 = 1 =  1^2 = (\frac{1}{n} \ n)^2 = (\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} 1)^2 $$

Comment: Thank you for the this remark. I have edited my question with at least two elements in the sequence.

Comment: Yes, to get inequality, I assume $a_1\lt a_n$ which implies that $n\gt1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
\bar{x}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\tag1
$$
If $x_i\le x_{i+1}$ and $x_1\lt x_n$, we can find a $k$ so that $x_k\le\bar{x}\lt x_{k+1}$. Then
$$
\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\ge0\iff i\ge n-k+1\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2-\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{n-i+1}
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\bar{x}-\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{n-i+1}\tag3\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\left(\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\right)\tag4\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-x_{n-k+1}\right)\left(\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: apply $(1)$
$(4)$: distributive property
$(5)$: subtract $\frac1nx_{n-k-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\right)=0$

Applying $(2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
i\ge n-k+1&\implies\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\ge0\quad\text{and}\quad x_i-x_{n-k+1}\ge0\tag6\\
i\lt n-k+1&\implies\bar{x}-x_{n-i+1}\lt0\quad\text{and}\quad x_i-x_{n-k+1}\le0\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the terms in $(5)$ are non-negative. Furthermore, either the $i=1$ term or the $i=n$ term of $(5)$ is positive; that is, $\bar{x}$ cannot equal either $x_1$ or $x_n$, and $x_{n-k+1}$ cannot equal both $x_1$ and $x_n$.

Summarizing, if $x_i\le x_{i+1}$ and $x_1\lt x_n$,
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{n-i+1}\lt\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2\tag8
$$

Comment: This seems quite a neat argument @robjohn. Question: How did you come up with the last equality? In other words, I can't seem to get how did you utilized the existence of $k$.

Comment: @venrey: I have added some explanation. If that does not answer your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n-i+1} < \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^2\iff\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n-i+1} < \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^2$$

When $n$ is odd one has $LHS=2(x_1x_n+\cdots+x_{\frac{n-1}{2}}x_{\frac{n+3}{2}})+x^2_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$

When $n$ is even one has $LHS=2(x_1x_n+\cdots+x_{\frac{n}{2}}x_{\frac{n+2}{2}})$

In both cases we have trivially that a sum of squares distinct of zero is greater than $0$.

$$0\lt n((x_n-x_1)^2+\cdots +(x_{\frac{n+3}{2}}-x_{\frac{n-1}{2}})^2)\text{ when n is odd               }\\0\lt n((x_n-x_1)^2+\cdots +(x_{\frac{n+2}{2}}-x_{\frac{n}{2}})^2)\text{ when n is even              }$$

Comment: Where do you use the monotonicity of $x_i$? Without that, the inequality is not necessarily true.

Comment: All the $(x_i-x_j)^2$ should be positive for this because the square of both $a_i-a_j$ and $a_j-a_i$ are equal and greater than zero.

Comment: Why the sign of edit? I don't have edit anything. Who put this "edit"?